# Can Apache Ivy handle dependencies in p2 repositories?

Tags: sbt, ivy, p2

I considered using SBT (which resolves dependencies using Ivy) to build an Eclipse RCP application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the p2 repository via the standard ivy resolvers(listed here: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) then it should be possible.