# How to build Eclipse plugin project with dependency on Eclipse Birt?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sbt, tycho

I have a set of Maven projects that I would like to migrate to SBT.

Tne only thing stopping me to do so, it's a project that is an Eclipse plugin, that has dependencies with Eclipse Birt.

The [Tycho plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) for Maven, handles all the dependencies.  This tool isn't available in SBT.  I've found [sbt-tycho](https://github.com/ashewring/sbt-tycho) plugin for SBT, but it looks like unmaintained (3 years with no activity).

Maybe I could build my Eclipse plugin with Maven, and the rest of projects with SBT.  But don't know if this is possible.

Other alternative is to use Gradle, by means of [the wuff plugin](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff).

Related questions in StackOverflow:

- [How to build an eclipse plugin with sbt and sbt-osgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741539/how-to-build-an-eclipse-plugin-with-sbt-and-sbt-osgi)
- [Can Apache Ivy handle dependencies in p2 repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256963/can-apache-ivy-handle-dependencies-in-p2-repositories)

But I prefer SBT before Maven or Gradle, in order not to introduce yet another language besides Scala.

Is it possible to have all projects in SBT except the one that uses Tycho (Eclipse plugin)?.  The Eclipse plugin project is a dependency of the main project, and it rarely changes.

Any ideas?

**Update 1**: additional information.  Eclipse plugins use the [p2 repository](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2) format for handling dependencies, instead of the standard Maven repository used for Gradle, Maven, Ivy and SBT.  That's why special tools are needed.  My custom Eclipse plugin has over 100 indirect p2 dependencies.

**Update 2**

`pom.xml` of my Eclipse plugin:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myCompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
  <properties>
    <tycho.version>0.19.0</tycho.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>eclipse</id>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>babel</id>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.11.1/kepler</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>logback</id>
      <url>http://logback.qos.ch/p2/</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
      <resolver>p2</resolver>
      <environments>
              <environment>
                <os>linux</os>
                <ws>gtk</ws>
                <arch>x86_64</arch>
              </environment>
              <environment>
                <os>win32</os>
                <ws>win32</ws>
                <arch>x86</arch>
              </environment>
      </environments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"Maybe I could build my Eclipse plugin with Maven, and the rest of projects with SBT. But don't know if this is possible."*? It is indeed possible to use Maven in a project and sbt in the others. Would you like to also keep the directory structure? How should the structure look like?

Comment: The directory structure can be changed if needed.

Comment: When is the Eclipse plugin project needed for the other projects? How are they related to each other?

Comment: There is a main project and several satellite ones.  One of the satellite ones is an Eclipse Plugin that provides custom data to Eclipse Birt.  The main project, uses the same Eclipse Birt plugins that the satellite one.  So, using the transitive dependencies of the custom Eclipse plugin, brings all needed Birt dependencies. The problem is that Eclipse plugins use a custom repository layout: "p2" instead of standard Maven layout.

Comment: Ah, so could that be that the real issue is the p2 repository layout? What's that?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2

Comment: Could you show a sample URL a dependency sits under? Something that I could use to deconstruct to create a Ivy2 template.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256963/can-apache-ivy-handle-dependencies-in-p2-repositories

Comment: Ivy does support p2 repositories, that uses the OSGi model for modeling dependencies http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/resolver/updatesite.html

Comment: More information about differences between Maven and p2 repositories: http://bkapukaranov.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/rt-meets-p2/

Comment: Updated to include the pom.xml of my simple Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [the support for Eclipse updatesite with OSGi bundles is already available in Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html). It doesn't however mean that the resolver can be used directly in sbt (I have never read about it and seen it in use before so I might be mistaken).

There's a way to include any resolver of Ivy in sbt using [externalIvySettings()](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#External+Maven+or+Ivy):

> create the configuration files as you would for Maven (`pom.xml`) or Ivy
>   (`ivy.xml` and optionally `ivysettings.xml`). External configuration is
>   selected by using one of the following expressions.

There's [Ivy settings (resolver configuration)](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Ivy+settings+%28resolver+configuration%29) with `externalIvySettings` and [Ivy file (dependency configuration)](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Ivy+file+%28dependency+configuration%29) with `externalIvyFile`.

My guess is that you might be quite successful leveraging the support. Just add `externalIvySettings` and/or `externalIvyFile` to `build.sbt`, and create `ivy.xml` in the top-level directory of the Eclipse plugin's project with a declaration of [Ivy's Eclipse updatesite resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/updatesite.html).

You may want to explore the support with the following `build.sbt`:

```
externalIvySettings()

libraryDependencies += "bundle" % "org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" % "3.100.1.v4234e"
```

Place `ivysettings.xml` in the project's top-level directory (alongside `build.sbt`):

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain">
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
      <updatesite name="eclipse-juno" url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

With the two files above I could `update` up to failing on some `package`s:

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/eclipse-p2/}eclipse-p2...
:: loading settings :: file = /Users/jacek/sandbox/eclipse-p2/ivysettings.xml
[warn]  module not found: package#org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2;[0.0.0,)
[warn] ==== central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/package/org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2/[revision]/org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2-[revision].pom
[warn]   -- artifact package#org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2;[0.0.0,)!org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2.jar:
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/package/org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2/[revision]/org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2-[revision].jar
[warn] ==== eclipse-juno: tried
[warn]  module not found: package#org.mozilla.xpcom;[0.0.0,)
[warn] ==== central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/package/org.mozilla.xpcom/[revision]/org.mozilla.xpcom-[revision].pom
[warn]   -- artifact package#org.mozilla.xpcom;[0.0.0,)!org.mozilla.xpcom.jar:
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/package/org.mozilla.xpcom/[revision]/org.mozilla.xpcom-[revision].jar
[warn] ==== eclipse-juno: tried
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: package#org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2;[0.0.0,): not found
[warn]  :: package#org.mozilla.xpcom;[0.0.0,): not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      package:org.eclipse.swt.accessibility2:[0.0.0,)
[warn]        +- bundle:org.eclipse.swt:[3.0.0,4.0.0)
[warn]        +- bundle:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64:3.100.1.v4234e (/Users/jacek/sandbox/eclipse-p2/build.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:eclipse-p2_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn]      package:org.mozilla.xpcom:[0.0.0,)
[warn]        +- bundle:org.eclipse.swt:[3.0.0,4.0.0)
[warn]        +- bundle:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64:3.100.1.v4234e (/Users/jacek/sandbox/eclipse-p2/build.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:eclipse-p2_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Thanks Jacek. When I have time, I'll try and tell you about it.

Comment: That'd be awesome since the area's not explored much (and since I'm new to it I'd appreciate any help). Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work, I receive `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` at `org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:336)`.  I like this solution because it's simple.

Comment: What sbt version are you using? Since the issue pops up in Ivy, it's related to the version you use.

Comment: The Ivy team has solved me this bug, but I've tried to use the corrected version with SBT, and it's too new, and some API changes have occurred.

Comment: Mind providing a link to the issue so I can learn what they've changed (and how it might affect sbt)? I **recommend** reporting an issue to upgrade Ivy to the latest version with the bug resolved in.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (I haven't tried yet) is to use the [sbt-osgi-manager](http://digimead.github.io/sbt-osgi-manager) plugin, designed for this purpose.  It is actively mantained.

I'll update this answer with my experiences.

**UPDATE**: it doesn't work for me in the first try.

The final solution is to use a standard Maven repository for the Birt plugins.  This solution is good for the embedding the Birt runtime, but not for a complete RCP app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Edited and placed in the answer the name of the plugin.  If the URL changes, it can be googled.